# Form gets pushed up with keyboard & how to remove Dropdown Arrow

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying develop an input form and currently the page looks like this, which is quite good:

[image: Reports Page]

However, there are a few things I can't figure out how to accomplish:

1. How can I remove the DropDown arrow icons?
2. When the user taps on a TextField to enter a date, the keyboard opens and smashes all the UI up, like in image below.
3. Is there a way to intercept the tap action on the TextField so I can prevent the keyboard from opening and instead, show a DatePicker? (So the user will see the TextField, but won't be able to edit it manually.)
   I've already opens a DatePicker when the user taps on the icon next to the TextField.

Here is how it looks when the keyboard opens:
[image]

The code for this page is long, so here is the full code [on GitHub](https://github.com/moti0375/tikal_time_tracker/blob/develop/lib/pages/reports/generate_report_page.dart).

Answer (score 3):

**1.** and **2.** are straight forward answers:

You can specify the [`iconSize`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/DropdownButton/iconSize.html) in your [`DropdownButton`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html) widgets to be `0.0`, which *effectively removes the icon*:

```
DropdownButton(
  iconSize: 0.0,
  ...
)
```

Because of [your `BoxDecoration`](https://github.com/moti0375/tikal_time_tracker/blob/develop/lib/pages/reports/generate_report_page.dart#L47), you will need to add a `Padding` to your `Text` widgets:

```
DropdownMenuItem<Project>(
  value: value,
  child: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
      child: Text(value.name, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0))));
```

You might want to adjust the `padding` value according to your needs.

To avoid the soft *keyboard pushing up your content*, you can specify [`resizeToAvoidBottomPadding`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Scaffold/resizeToAvoidBottomPadding.html) to be `false` in your [`Scaffold`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Scaffold-class.html), which should be on top of your widget tree:

```
Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
  ...
)
```

For **3.** I think that you then should not be using a `TextField`, but rather a *`Text`* with a [`GestureDetector`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html) or [`InkWell`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html) (`InkWell` grants some Material highlight an splash effects) because you do *not need the properties of a `TextField` in that case*:

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    // Your code to show the DatePicker and make use of it.
    showDatePicker();
    ...
  },
  child: Text(dateText)
)
```

Comment: Thanks! 
The first just fixed the scroll problem.
When set the icon size to 0, the box decoration border go over the text.

Comment: @MotiBartov Then you just surround your `Text` inside the `DropdownMenuItem` with a `Padding`. Look at my adjusted answer for that.

Answer (score 1):

Good morning,

So for the first question I'm not sure if it's currently possible, but one way to do it, is to set the iconSize at 0.0
I'm not able to test it right now but it should works.

The second one, is caused by 2 Scaffold in one page. I can see a BottomNavBar that must be in a Scaffold and I'm pretty sure that the "input form" page is also in a Scaffold, so remove the scaffold from this page and the problem will be solved.

For the third one, I'll recommend to not use a TextField to opening a DatePicker, it's absolutely not recommended. You can create a widget that looks like a textfield and intercept the "onTap" with a GestureDetector.

Hoping this will help you,

Have a nice day

Comment: Hi, Thanks! 
If I remove the scaffold from the page, how can I have the app bar on it?
However, I managed it by using resizeToAvoidBottomPadding, this solved the problem. 
As for DropDown Icon, I've tried to set it to 0, but then the BoxDecoration with the border, goes over the text inside. 

I will try for other approach with the Input field, replace it with Text

Comment: If you want app bar in the view you can create a custom one and used it in a Stack, but if resizeToAvoidBottomPadding works you are fine. For the DropDown Icon there is no other solution atm ...